# Any way to one-time TRANSFER / MOVE Kindle books to a separate account?

Tags: kindle

Presumably transferring Kindle ebooks to someone else isn't allowed in general, but has anyone found a way (or contacted Amazon Support for them to successfully do this manually, on their side?) to split a Kindle account and/or one-time transfer/move several Kindle ebooks to a separate account?  A friend and I had multiple Kindle devices using the same user/login ten years ago when we worked together, and over time, ended up with hundreds of ebooks (including his many sci-fi books) in one single Kindle account.  I'd ideally like to choose about 20 of mine that I still care about and separate them out to a new/separate Kindle account, instead of wading through all his books to find things in my library.  And then going forward, I'll only use my own separate account from now on, so hence, this is only a one-time splitting of the account, no ongoing or future ebook transfers needed. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This topic has been discussed in hundreds of threads on dozens of websites.

> Presumably transferring Kindle ebooks to someone else isn't allowed in general. But still... has anyone found a way (or contacted Amazon Support for them to successfully do this manually, on their side?) to split a Kindle account or one-time transfer several Kindle ebooks to a separate account?

As per Amazon user agreement **you're not purchasing a book**. You're purchasing a not-shareable, not-transferable licensee for reading these books. And -- for the sake of truth -- this was forced on Amazon by book's publishers, not "invented" by Amazon itself.

Therefore, sorry to say this, but asking, if:

- there any possibility of transferring books between accounts
- you could contact Amazon support and ask them to do so
- someone found any magical glitch for doing so

is unfortunately pointless.

If there would be *any way* of doing so then Amazon itself would be in a seriously legal troubles, because that would be a direct violation of all agreements that Amazon signed with book publishers.

> A friend and I had multiple Kindle devices using the same user/login ten years ago when we worked together

If I may suggest anything, I'd seriously think this over and would *not contact* Amazon support at all with this. Using single account by two or more users is a direct violation of Amazon's user agreement.

Registering separate account is free, there's a Amazon Household, so there are options to legally share content and not share access credentials (which is illegal).

> I'd ideally like to choose about 20 of mine that I still care about and separate them out to a new/separate Kindle account, instead of wading through all his books to find things in my library

If you search over the Internet, you'll find narrow situations like a married couple  getting a divorce and asking how to split their Amazon Household's mutual purchases. And there's even a suggestion to evaluate actual / current value of all the books to be split, exchange this in money and purchase them again, on a new account (enrolled by one person after divorce), because **transferring content from one account to another is impossible** in Amazon.